# Youtube video embeded link (their own host) looks horrible, almost like 3d, but on their website it looks fine

Tags: youtube, embedding

For example this link

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/7prYFY4wqdY?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1&controls=0&rel=0&wmode=transparent
```

makes the video green and purple, and everything is misaligned.

but directly on their site, it plays fine. What could be causing this?

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7prYFY4wqdY
```

Comment: what's the html that shows in the response?

Comment: There is no html response, it's a straight youtube link that causes the error, it's not specific to my host or site in any way.

Comment: look at the response in 'view source' or chrome/firefox  developer windows.

Comment: There are a couple errors [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Zib77zd.png) but nothing that helps me. I've disabled all chrome extensions but lastpass in incognito, but nothing helps. I've tried safari, and it works there for some reason. Thanks @Mecon

Comment: My bad, you meant the HTML source, not JS console errors. Let me see if there is anything obvious there too.

Comment: Nothing in the source helps me.

Comment: Perhaps this is about the way embed link is declared. Is this in an IFrame? And does it have parameters like width, height? see this link for parameters that can be given. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player

Comment: Thanks for your continued attempts @Mecon. I'm not talking about any embed link, it's a straight google embed link, even with no parameters, it's still messed up `https://www.youtube.com/embed/7prYFY4wqdY`. It's the HTML5 version they are serving. I noticed a div with a class of `webgl` once I delete that, it looks fine. I'm off to google that issue.